# can flake8 *fix* my python whitespace problems?

Tags: python, flake8

I just learned about [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/), which calls itself "Flake8: Your Tool For Style Guide Enforcement." While flake8 will find many Python whitespace errors and enforce [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it does not appear to have an option to automatically fix problematic python code.

[autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8) does appear to have this option (called `--in-place`), but flake8 seems to have much wider support.

Is there a way to make flake8 fix my code?

Comment: no, `flake8` is a linter only -- you'll want a code formatter to do code formatting (such as autopep8 / add-trailing-comma / yapf / black / etc.)

Comment: @AnthonySottile, thanks. If you can make that an answer, I can accept it. I'm unclear why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

no, flake8 is a linter only -- that is, it only checks your code.  (technically, flake8 doesn't even check your code -- it is just a framework for other linters to plug into and provides inclusion / exclusion / etc. on top of other tools)

if you want something which fixes your code, you'll want a code formatter to do code formatting (such as autopep8 / add-trailing-comma / yapf / black / etc.)